# Where Layout Inspector shows where is the ID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, layout-inspector

How can I using Android studio 3.0 see which part of code  is corresponding to the layout on my emulator?

The most logical way would be to refer to the single `@id`s  but from the tool `Layout Inspector` but **how can i see the name of the layout(or nested layouts) that are appearing on the snapshot?** And the name of the single Ids?

If I open the `View Tree` I do not see any specific Id( the ones are actually in the code but some generics ID that descend by a generic `Decor View` with id as `id/toolbaar` or `id/0x0` instead of the real part of the code where I want to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Properties table under properties, you should see an attribute by the name of mID. That's the id you're looking for.

**EDIT after comment:**
For newer versions of Android Studio (eg Dolphin), There is a tab on the left side of the layout inspector menu (Tools -> Layout Inspector) called "Components". This holds the entire tree with the views hierarchy. Expanding it all the way reveals the view IDs and their values

Comment: really good to know, hope google will make it more highlight, visible for everybody does not know this trick, is really  useful to know where to touch the code

Comment: It took me ages to figure it out myself when I first needed it!

Comment: Is this still correct in 2022? There is only an "Attributes" window and there is no mID there...

Comment: @Maddis I've updated my answer, thanks for bringing that to my attention